Adding a modifiable property to TextTheme in Flutter
I'm trying to add a property to TextTheme that I can modify in my ThemeData. I've declared the following extension
extension CustomStyles on TextTheme{
  TextStyle get disabledText => const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff999999));
}

which I can apply to a textField using
child: (_isEnabled)
  ? Text("Undo", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
  : Text("Undo", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.disabledText)

However, when I try and access it in the ThemeData (declared in the same dart file as the extension)
theme: ThemeData (
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    bodyMedium: TextStyle(
      color: (_isDark) ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
      fontSize: _textSize
    ),
    disabledText: TextStyle(
      fontSize: _textSize
    ),
  ),
),

The compiler gives me the error
The named parameter 'disabledText' isn't defined

Any thoughts on how I might define it so I can have both the color and size defined by the theme?
=== Update ===
So, after Dhafin's comment I've got around this at the moment by declaring a static variable with the color and using the following
Text(item.text,
  style:          Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(color: MyAppState.disabledText))

but the question still remains. There has to be a more elegant way of declaring a central disabled theme that can be accessed anywhere

That's not how extensions work. By defining an extension getter disabledText, you'll be able to call it from an instance of TextTheme. Say you have final foo = TextTheme();, then later you can access foo.disabledText. It won't add anything to the TextTheme() constructor. See: https://dart.dev/language/extension-methods

Yes, Compiler is right.
You have only defined a getter method on the TextTheme class.
extension CustomStyles on TextTheme{
  TextStyle get disabledText => const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff999999));
}

This getter method is not an instance attribute (data member) that can be passed in the constructor of the class being extended by extension method.
TextTheme(
 disabledText: ..... // this data member is not defined.
 )

That's why extension method called 'extension method' not extension property or extension generally.
So, for your problem: Provide all of the visual properties of that TextStyle on the extension.
    extension CustomStyles on TextTheme{
      TextStyle get disabledText => const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff999999), fontSize: 20);
}

and you can access it throught: Theme.of(context).textTheme.disabledText
And, if you wanna dynamically display that disabledText with various font sizes:
extension CustomStyles on TextTheme{
  TextStyle getDisabledText ({required int fontSize})=>TextStyle(
       color: Color(0xff999999), fontSize: fontSize);
    
        }

For more info about extension method here
Hope it helps you.

Thanks - it doesn't help because the whole point of the original attempt is to allow it to access the text size dynamically as per the bodyMedium. But yes, I now see what the extension method is doing thanks to Dhafin's comment and your answer

easy easy, but it can be customized, see updates.

Thanks - I see where you are going with that. Appreciate your help

Having read around a bit more I came across this article on Medium which lead me to this solution
extension CustomStyles on BuildContext {
  TextStyle get disabledTextTheme => Theme.of(this).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(color: Color(0xff999999));
}

Which can be applied to my textField as follows
child: (_isEnabled)
  ? Text("Undo", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
  : Text("Undo", style: context.disabledTextTheme)

